# How to pass default image to previous activity if no image is selected

Tags: java, android, image, android-camera

In my app, I have a camera function. User can capture image or pick from gallery.

**Activity B**

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                    imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                }

                break;

            case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        selectedImage = imageUri;
                        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                        imageView.setImageURI(null);
                        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                    }
                }
        }
    }

 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                if(selectedImage!=null) {
                    returnIntent.putExtra("img_uri", selectedImage.toString());
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

When submit button is clicked, it will return to previous activity.

**Activity A**

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                imgURI = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("img_uri"));
                if (mClickedPosition == -1) { 
                    if (obj != null)
                        obj.addNewItem(imgURI);
                } else {
                    if (obj != null)
                     obj.changeItem(mClickedPosition, imgURI);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> My question now is how to pass a default image to Activity A If
>   user didn't select any image ?

This is the xml `imageView` in **Activity B**

```
  <ImageView
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="330dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/no_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_weight="0.50" />
```

If no image selected, I want `@mipmap/no_image` return to Activity B. Is it possible ? Thanks.

Comment: Add to `switch` `default` and set image.

Comment: @dieter_h where should I add the switch default ? Activity A ?

Comment: URI is a subclass of string.  Where is the default URI in your code?

Comment: @danny117 where should I put the URI ? In activity A or B

Comment: @Seng You should have to first set default image in imageview of Activity A then in onActivityResult check if intent has extra or uri is recieved from Activity B then set image from uri otherwise default image is already set.

Comment: like what @Rajesh said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an Uri of your image stored in resources by the next way:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        if(selectedImage!=null) {
            returnIntent.putExtra("img_uri", selectedImage.toString());
        } else {
            returnIntent.putExtra("img_uri", Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/mipmap/no_image").toString());
        }
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Then you can use it as usual Uri to show the image in `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

ByDefault set value of `selectedImage` to "default".

Now in your `addNewItem()` and `changeItem()` check value passed in `imageUri`

```
if(imageUri.equalsIgnoreCase("default"))
    // set your default image that is @mipmap/no_image
else
    // set image you are getting from imageUri
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                    imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                }else{
                   //set default
                }

                break;

            case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        selectedImage = imageUri;
                        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                        imageView.setImageURI(null);
                        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }else{
                     //set default
                }
          default{ 
                     //set default 
                 }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you tell me how can I set "@mipmap/no_image to imageView ?

Comment: Add image to `drawable` [hdpi, xhdpi, etc] folder, then set `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.<your_image>)`

Comment: put this line inside else ?

Comment: If you want to set default image

Comment: How can I return the default image in Activity A if no image is selected ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return a default image to Activity A. Like others wrote, you just have to prepare for the condition when the user doesn't select any image.
Modify your onActivityResult for Activity A like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(data!=null){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                    imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        selectedImage = imageUri;
                        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
            //Your default image goes here, when the user doesn't select either of the two options
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.<default_image>);
                break;
        }
 }
```